# Why does clicking the volume down button decrement correctly while volume up button increases to the max

Tags: javascript, dom-events

In my music player, whenever I click on the volume down button it decrements down by 10 as expected in my event listeners callback function. But, using the same logic for the volume up button, instead of increasing by 10 for the value, it goes from the current value all the way up to the max which is 100. Why is this the case and how do I fix it?

```js
const music = document.querySelector('audio');
const volume_slider = document.getElementById('volume_slider');
const volume_down = document.getElementById('down');
const volume_up = document.getElementById('up');

function setVolume() {
  music.volume = volume_slider.value / 100;
}

volume_down.addEventListener('click', () => {
  volume_slider.value -= 10;
  setVolume();
  console.log(music.volume)
});
volume_up.addEventListener('click', () => {
  volume_slider.value += 10;
  setVolume();
  console.log(music.volume)
});
```

```html
<div class="player-container">
    <audio src="music/BioUnit.mp3"></audio> 
    <div class="volume-container">
        <div class="volume">
            <button id="down">Down</button>
            <input type="range" min="0" max="100" value="50" step="10" id="volume_slider" onChange="setVolume()">
            <button id="up">Up</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: your code looks fine, so you _really_ want to create a [mcve] here.

Comment: What is `previousBtn` and `nextBtn` and `previousSong` and why is `music.volume` a global?

Comment: You need to look at how to pass the element to the event handler https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Building_blocks/Events 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/click_event   https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/change_event

Comment: @MarkSchultheiss I have included the full html and js code so you can see everything. This is just a personal project to build my skills and not going to be used for anything important although I do not see where in my code music.volume is global?

Comment: Please see the edited code to learn what a ___minimal___ reproducible example is.

Comment: @Programmer So the above edited code is what I should have posted?

Comment: @RandyGoldsmith exactly, no one needs all the bootstrap icons, song title and author, etc. ...

Comment: @RandyGoldsmith if you already put bootstrap icons in your StackOverflow snippet though its a question about volume changing and not about bootstrap icons, you should at least include the bootstrap library so one can click  the up / downn buttons ( in your original code there was nothing to click on ...)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it comes from the fact that the value is a string. See example below:

```js
const music = document.getElementById("music");
const volume_slider = document.getElementById('volume_slider');
const volume_down = document.getElementById('down');
const volume_up = document.getElementById('up');

function setVolume() {
  music.volume = volume_slider.value / 100;
}

volume_down.addEventListener('click', () => {
  console.log(typeof volume_slider.value)
  var oldValue = Number(volume_slider.value)
  volume_slider.value = oldValue - 10;
  setVolume();
  console.log(music.volume)
});
volume_up.addEventListener('click', () => {
  console.log(typeof volume_slider.value)
  var oldValue = Number(volume_slider.value)
  volume_slider.value = oldValue + 10;
  setVolume();
  console.log(music.volume)
});
```

```html
<audio id="music"></audio>
<div class="volume-container">
  <div class="volume">
    <button id="down">Down</button>
    <input type="range" min="0" max="100" value="50" step="10" id="volume_slider" onChange="setVolume()">
    <button id="up">Up</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: "See example above:" above what?

Comment: I moved the text without changing that word, my bad

Comment: all good, just wanted to ensure your intent

Comment: Thanks Jason, that did the trick! Your exactly right, value is a string and I am doing math with a string and number.

Comment: @RandyGoldsmith, lol, I wouldnt have come to it either ... But just think of it, DIVIDING ASTRING BY A NUMBER LMAO

Answer (score 0):

Add some events and dispatch on the up/down one of those events - added an indicator result and remove some unknown/undefined stuff.

Made the values number by multiply by 1 to make it obvious.

```js
const volume_slider = document.getElementById('volume_slider');
const volume_down = document.getElementById('down');
const volume_up = document.getElementById('up');
let music = {
  volumn: 0
};
const eventV = new Event('volume');

function setVolume(v) {
  console.log("v:", v, typeof v);
  volume_slider.value = (volume_slider.value * 1) + (v * volume_slider.step);
  console.log(volume_slider.value)
  music.volume = volume_slider.value / 100;
  volume_slider.dispatchEvent(eventV);
}

volume_slider.addEventListener('volume', function(e) {
  console.log("what to do:", e.target.value);
  const result = document.querySelector('#result');
  result.textContent = `You like ${event.target.value}`;
}, false);

function handleClicker(e) {
  let v = e.target.dataset.volume * 1;
  console.log("change by:", v);
  setVolume(v);
}
volume_slider.addEventListener('change', (event) => {
  event.target.dispatchEvent(eventV);
});

volume_down.addEventListener('click', handleClicker);
volume_up.addEventListener('click', handleClicker);
```

```html
<div class="volume-container">
  <div class="volume">
    <i class="fas fa-volume-down" data-volume="-10" id="down">down</i>
    <input type="range" min="0" max="100" value="50" step="1" id="volume_slider">
    <i class="fas fa-volume-up" data-volume="10" id="up">up</i>
  </div>
</div>
<div id="result"></div>
```

Comment: @Programmer - added a log to the volume event to make it more obvious - probably needs more work but the click and change now do something at least